# projective dimension over local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

My question is as below.

Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring such that $m$ consists of zero divisors. Prove that if $A$ is a finitely generated R-module, then $pd_R(A)$, the projective dimension of $A$ over $R$, is either $0$ or infinite.

Using {zero divisors of R} = union of minimal prime ideal and prime avoidance, I found that Krull dimension of R is zero. I tried to use the fact 'any projective module over a local ring is free' but I failed. I will wait your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Check Auslander-Buchsbaum criterion.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mohan! This Criterion is very useful to solve problems